# How to remove directory with invalid name on running system root partition without third party software?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, file-permissions

Somehow, most probably from one or another usb-born Linux, I got cute little directory named C: located on my C: NTFS partition, due to its peculiar name I can not operate on its directory tree as deleting C: is a no no operation after all...

[image: Evil C: ! Run for your lives!]

rmdir, del, move, copy all have no effect, and even show some signs of undefined behavior (for example del asks to delete \*).

Checkdisk failed to complete. (I have a bad feeling about this.)

Environment is up-to-date Windows 8.1 in English localization with full admin privileges.

I will be doing full format of this disk in few days anyway and all data are backed up so crazy ideas have green light.

Comment: did you try booting in Safe Mode? Keep pressing F8 during boot up to get to safe mode.

Comment: @ChrisinNL it changes nothing. This is issue on filesystem level created by bug in third party filesystem driver.

Comment: @DavidPostill not exactly. Answers from that questions did not work in my case. There are few differences between file and directory ;)

Comment: @Sott it did not work, I did my share of googling before posting ;)